# In pandas, what's the difference between df['column'] and df.column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working my way through Pandas for Data Analysis and learning a ton. However, one thing keeps coming up. The book typically refers to columns of a dataframe as `df['column']` however, sometimes without explanation the book uses `df.column`.

I don't understand the difference between the two. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is come code demonstrating the what I am talking about:

```
In [5]:

import pandas as pd

data = {'column1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
        'column2': [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
df

Out[5]:
column1 column2
0    a   1
1    a   4
2    a   2
3    b   5
4    c   3
5 rows × 2 columns
```

---

**df.column:**

```
In [8]:

df.column1
Out[8]:
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    c
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

---

**df['column']:**

```
In [9]:

df['column1']
Out[9]:
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    c
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, but LMK if there are any intricacies I missed. I'm not a Pandas expert, but they seem to be the same.

Answer (score 11):

for setting, values, you need to use `df['column'] = series`.

once this is done however, you can refer to that column in the future with `df.column`, assuming it's a valid python name. (so `df.column` works, but `df.6column` would still have to be accessed with `df['6column']`)

i think the subtle difference here is that when you set something with `df['column'] = ser`, pandas goes ahead and adds it to the columns/does some other stuff (i believe by overriding the functionality in `__setitem__`. if you do `df.column = ser`, it's just like adding a new field to any existing object which uses `__setattr__`, and pandas does not seem to override this behavior.

Comment: furthermore, you can have spaces in the column name, e.g. ``df['column foo bar']``, while using ``df.column foo bar`` is an error