# What is difference between DataFrame attribute and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [66]: data
Out[66]: 
   col1 col2 label
0   1.0    a     c
1   2.0    b     d
2   3.0    c     e
3   0.0    d     f
4   4.0    e     0
5   5.0    f     0

In [67]: data.label
Out[67]: 
0      c
1      d
2    NaN
3      f
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: col2, dtype: object

In [68]: data['label']
Out[68]: 
0    c
1    d
2    e
3    f
4    0
5    0
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Why data.label and data['label'] showing different results?

Answer (score 2):

The big difference I've noticed is assignment.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

s = "SummerCrime|WinterCrime".split("|")
j = {x: [random.choice(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"]) for j in range(300)] for x in s}
df = pd.DataFrame(j)
df.FallCrime = [random.choice(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"]) for j in range(300)]
```

Gives: `UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name`

However, there are also [docs associated with this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access), which has the following warnings which may be related to your problem:

> - You can use this access only if the index element is a valid Python identifier, e.g. `s.1` is not allowed. See [here for an explanation of valid identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).
> - The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. `s.min` is not allowed, but `s['min']` is possible.
> - Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: `index`, `major_axis`, `minor_axis`, `items`.
> - In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. `s['1']`, `s['min']`, and `s['index']` will access the corresponding element or column.

They go on to say:

> You can use attribute access to modify an existing element of a Series or column of a DataFrame, but be careful; if you try to use attribute access to create a new column, it creates a new attribute rather than a new column. **In 0.21.0 and later, this will raise a `UserWarning`**

So it's possible you did this without realizing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two is related to assignment. with `data.label` you cannot assign the values to column.

data.label is to access the attributes and data["label"] is to assign the values.

Also if you have spaces in your column name, for example `df['label name']`, while using `data.label name` will through an error.

For more information see this  [Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546555/in-pandas-whats-the-difference-between-dfcolumn-and-df-column)