# What is the difference between calling "iris.species" and "iris['species']"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have just recently started on python data science and noticed that i can call the columns of a dataset in two ways. I was wondering if there was an advantage to using one method over the other or can they be used interchangeably?

```
import seaborn
iris = seaborn.load_dataset('iris')

print(iris.species)
print(iris['species'])
```

Both print statements give the same output in Jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. `iris` is a Pandas Dataframe, and these are two different ways to access a column in a Dataframe.

Try this:

```
iris['species'] is iris.species
# True
```

You can use either method, but I find the indexing approach (`iris['species']`) is more versatile, e.g. you can use it to access columns whose names contain spaces, you can use it to create new columns, and you won't ever accidentally retrieve a dataframe method or attribute (e.g. `iris.shape`) instead of a column.

Also see answers to these questions:

- [In pandas, what's the difference between df['column'] and df.column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546555/in-pandas-whats-the-difference-between-dfcolumn-and-df-column)
- [For Pandas DataFrame, what's the difference between using squared brackets or dot to access a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/for-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-do)

Comment: Thank you! This really helped! Also thanks for the links as well, I was googling for "iris.series vs iris['series']" but nothing really came up

Comment: You're welcome! There's also a little mention of it in the pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), but nothing very systematic. You may be able to find a more complete discussion elsewhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods of accessing the dictionary are equivalent.

The main advantage of accessing the `iris` dictionary via its `'species'` key (e.g. `iris['species']`) is that the specified dictionary key can have spaces.

For example, you can access the `iris` dictionary with a `'plant color'` key like so: `iris['plant color']`. However, you cannot access the `iris` dictionary via `iris.plant color`.

Comment: Thanks natn2323 for helping to clarify! :)

Comment: Thanks natn2323 for helping to clarify! :)